# WebSockets in Create React App with Webpack proxy

Tags: reactjs, webpack, websocket, signalr, create-react-app

I created my React app using Create React App in version 3.1.2 (19 Sept 2019). I was trying to configure proxy for Web Socket requests, but it seems that when I am using the proxy, the connection is not established. I have used [THIS](https://github.com/Ibro/AspNetCoreSignalR_React) example to set up my things. The server is Asp.Net Core as in example and it works as long as it has the address wired into the initalization. This snippet works:

```
const hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("https://localhost:44392/chatHub")
  .build();
```

And this doesn't:

```
const hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("chatHub")
  .build();
```

With this:

```
{
  "proxy": "https://localhost:44392/",
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2"
  },
(...)
```

I saw a suggestion [HERE](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy) that I might use an object in proxy setup, but when I tried I got an error that proxy address has to be a single string, not an object:

```
 proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: '<url>',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      },
      '^/foo': {
        target: '<other_url>'
      }
```

Comment: Try adding a slash before, like `.withUrl("/chatHub")`

Comment: Doesn't help. Connection is blocked on pending status. If you try to send a message, you get "Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.".

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @Alexandre - the answer provided by neeko was OK for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reposting a solution I posted here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5280

I had a problem where I couldn't proxy requests (in development) to my own websocket (socket-io) server.

I followed the steps here: [create-react-app proxying requests in dev](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/), my `setupProxy.js` looked like this:

**The below did not work for proxying a websocket connection:**

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5011',
    }),
  );
  app.use(
    '/socket-io',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5011',
      ws: true,
    }),
  );
};
```

However, the hot reloading wouldn't work because somehow this interfered with webpack dev servers websocket connection. I would see this error in the console:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /sockjs-node from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5011 (ECONNRESET) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

**I got this working by doing the following:**

```
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

const socket = isDev 
? io.connect('http://localhost:5011', { path: '/socket-io' }) 
: io.connect({ path: '/socket-io' });
```

Hope this helps someone out! Let me know if there's a better way to do this

Comment: Not a perfect solution for those who want to use cookies attached to the same domain..

Comment: @neeko I don't understand where the code about "I got this working by doing the following:" is written ?

Comment: @nlips this is where I defined my websocket connection

Comment: @neeko so you don't really proxy the query

Comment: I had a very similar problem to yours. Wrapping both the path and the target inside createProxyMiddleware fixed it for me.

Answer (score 14):

For me, proxying a specific route under `/api` as a websocket route didn't worked with the previously suggested `src\setupProxy.js`configurations.

But this works:

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        createProxyMiddleware('/api',{
            target: 'http://localhost:9800',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );

    app.use(
        createProxyMiddleware('/api/notification/register', {
            target: 'ws://localhost:9800',
            ws: true,
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

And this actually produce a meaningful HPM output:

```sh
[HPM] Proxy created: /api  -> http://localhost:9800
[HPM] Proxy created: /api/notification/register  -> ws://localhost:9800
```

Comment: This is the answer that finally worked for me for Websockets. . Even the accepted answer didn't. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

After searching a bit, I finally found a solution https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually

First, install `http-proxy-middleware`. Next, create `src/setupProxy.js` and place the following contents in it:

```js
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    proxy({
        target: '<url>',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
    })
  );
  app.use(
    '/foo',
    proxy({
        target: '<other_url>'
    })
  );
};
```