# Trying to access from React to my websocket which is Django channels but it raises error "No route found"

Tags: reactjs, django-channels

**My websocket works because i tested it from django side white simple chat app**. The route also works which is http://localhost:8000/chat/room. But It doesnt work on react side. It says No route found for path 'chat/myroom'. I've been trying to solve this for 2 hours, as a last hope, I wanted to ask here.

My routing.py file

```
from django.urls import re_path

from api import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

My roomPage.js file

```
`import React from "react";
import useWebSocket, { ReadyState } from "react-use-websocket";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";


export default function RoomPage() {
  
  const { readyState } = useWebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/myroom", {
    onOpen: () => {
      console.log("Connected!");
    },
    onClose: () => {
      console.log("Disconnected!");
    }
  });

  const connectionStatus = {
    [ReadyState.CONNECTING]: "Connecting",
    [ReadyState.OPEN]: "Open",
    [ReadyState.CLOSING]: "Closing",
    [ReadyState.CLOSED]: "Closed",
    [ReadyState.UNINSTANTIATED]: "Uninstantiated"
  }[readyState];

  return (
    <div>
      <span>The WebSocket is currently {connectionStatus}</span>
    </div>
  );
}`
```

I tried on django side and it worked! But react side doesn't working

Comment: You may find this thread useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58088218/websockets-in-create-react-app-with-webpack-proxy

Answer (score 0):

After +10 hours i finally found the solution and I want to kill myself! The only problem is calling websocket without "end slash"

**Wrong!**

```
useWebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/myroom"
```

**Works**

```
useWebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/myroom/"
```